# How to view what version of angular depend each library of package.json

Tags: angular, dependencies, package.json, nrwl-nx, nx-workspace

I need to check what version of angular need each library installed on my angular app, because one of them are broken my nx-workspace applicacion.
How can I see that information? .

Comment: Are you using `npm`? or do you use another package manager?

Comment: Usually I use npm. But I think I can try with yarn in case is there any solution